# how to create checksums while images are captured with gphoto2

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create an MD5 hash for each shot captured with gphoto2.

I tried to run this command

```
sudo gphoto2 -capture-image-and-download -force-overwrite \
 -filename capture.jpg -I 10 && md5sum capture.jpg > md5.txt
```

but the checksum writes only when gphoto2 was stopped. I need to write it for each shot as it is captured?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are only summing one file. Does gphoto2 write the file incrementally? Because if not, there's no benefit to piping it.

Comment: @RobinGreen The images are captured every 10 seconds. The OP wants to have an MD5 for each snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

[**gphoto2**](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html) versions newer than 2.3.0 have the option `--hook-script FILENAME`; you could write a short script file, e. g. named `hook.sh`:

```
case $ACTION in download) md5sum "$ARGUMENT" >md5.txt
esac
```

(don't forget to make it executable) and then

```
sudo gphoto2 -capture-image-and-download -force-overwrite \
 -filename capture.jpg -I 10 --hook-script hook.sh
```